# Have a resizable div honoring a given width in px and max-width of 100%

Tags: css, resize

I have a div inside another div. The outer div has a given width, but max-width should be 100%. The inner div is resizable but somehow the outer div doesn't seem to care whether or not the inner div gets wider. A scrollbar is displayed instead of sizing with the inner box to a maximum of 100%.

This fiddle demonstrates the issue; how can I have a div with a given width in px, set the inner div to resizable and have the outer div listen to the inner div's current width and size up to a maximum of 100%?

[JSFiddle with the example](https://jsfiddle.net/rfc709rz/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">resize me...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer { 
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #ededed;
    border: 1px solid #f90;
}

#inner { 
    overflow: auto;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 15px;
    resize: both;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS (or replace it):

```
#outer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

#inner {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Live preview: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfc709rz/1/)

Comment: Simple and great. Works like a charm! Thanks, +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove "width: 200px;" and add "float: left;" to "#outer"

Here is the code:

```
#outer {
overflow: auto;
min-width: 200px;
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 100px;
background: #ededed;
border: 1px solid #f90;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution almost worked, had to add the width to the inner div to make it work. I chose the other answer because there's not float needed which I prefer over this. +1 for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

see if this helps.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#outer {
  /*   min-width: 200px;*/
  /*    max-width: 100%; */
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #ededed;
  border: 1px solid #f90;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#inner {
  overflow: auto;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 15px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">resize me...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The outer div will still need a max-width of 100% (otherwise people can resize it outside the browsers width). +1 for your effort. An accepted answer is chosen already.